# Sending html attribute / jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

Earlier today I asked a question about getting html from the PHP without JS, but now I did it with JQuery, I know have this below:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pewc_group_3414_3415");
    $(".pewc-item-field-wrapper").click(function(){
        var subtotal_fg = x.item(0).getAttribute("data-field-price");
      console.log(subtotal_fg);
    })
 });
}(jQuery));
```

Everytime someone clicks on a product the price is going up and filled in the data-field-price attribute. That is working fine! But I am checking if the price if 14.99 or less in the PHP before submitting or after submitting to Adding them to cart.

When I console_log the subtotal_fg it gives me on each click the right value. But HOW can I pass this value to PHP when clicking on the form or before clicking on the form because PHP needs to check some rules. Please help.

Comment: Use `ajax` for that

Comment: Any example for that?

Comment: You will have to use AJAX; since PHP is Server-Side, JS/jQuery is Client-side, the two cannot talk directly. You have to use HTTP to POST or GET data from the client (Browser) to the server (PHP). So if you want to send the value in `subtotal_fg` to PHP, you must use AJAX.